# button is not appeared after adding icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have an XML below. Here i want to show an icon at the top of the screen and two buttons at the bottom. Though i've done all the xml both for buttons and image icon. But it only shows the icon not the buttons. Please help me editing my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageViewPic"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_final"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

       />

        <Button

            android:id="@+id/Button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Candidate"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:background="#AA348C90"
            />

       <Button

            android:id="@+id/Button2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Voter"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
           android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
           android:background="#AA348C90"
           >

       </Button>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try decreasing  android:layout_marginTop="430dp" of your button

Comment: Now it shows only the 1st button the 2nd button which lays under the 1st button is not displayed while running. What can i do now, please suggest me editing my code. Here is the link  http://codepad.org/aKC7PT2S

Comment: you can show a picture of how it should look like?

Answer (score 0):

Change xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageViewPic"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_final"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

   />

    <Button
        android:layout_below="@+id/ImageViewPic"
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Candidate"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:background="#AA348C90"
        />

   <Button
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button1"
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Voter"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="20dp"

       android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
       android:background="#AA348C90">

   </Button></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Now it shows only the 1st button the 2nd button which lays under the 1st button is not displayed while running. What can i do now, please suggest me editing my code. http://codepad.org/aKC7PT2S

Comment: share your java code if it show in xml and did not display it mean you may be hide it from code

Comment: Yep, it shows image and the first  button only and the second button is still missing though i coded it.

Comment: I made some changes in the code now copy the xml and run again i hope it will work